# Importing Spark avro packages into a dockerized python project to import avro file in S3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, avro, spark-avro

I am trying to read some avro files stored in S3 bucket with the following code. spark version is 2.4.7

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Statistics').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("s3://test/sqoopData/part-m-00000.avro")
df.show()
```

With this im getting the below error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:678)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:652)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:652)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:652)
```

I know this is due to not having spark avro packages within my project. But Im not sure how to import those into my project. Please note that all spark, hadoop and python are setup using a docker file. therefore some solutions given in the internet couldn't be applied. eg importing required jar files using spark shell.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this setup https://github.com/kurtzace/python-spark-avro-query  (dockerfile within it)

- This solution loads avro jar into spark jars
- sets up spark home
- also exposes the avro file as an API (main.py)